# How to delete specific block in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have lines similar to following code many times in a notepad++ file. I like to delete it.. starting with first '(' and ending to '/'. Please suggest me automatic way in Find-Replace to do so..

(
  AA                NUMBER(15),

SS          NUMBER,

FF  NUMBER,

VV                 VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),

BB             VARCHAR2(600 CHAR),

BB1          VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),

SW           VARCHAR2(600 CHAR),

AS         NUMBER(15),

FF         NUMBER(15),

GR          DATE,

SWE          DATE,

DFD             CHAR(1 CHAR),

AA            CHAR(1 CHAR),

FG            DATE,

FES            DATE,

AAQ      NUMBER(10)             NOT NULL,

DDE           NUMBER(10)             DEFAULT 0                     NOT NULL,

SAqa         VARCHAR2(80 CHAR)      NOT NULL

)

LOGGING

NOPARALLEL

/

Comment: You will probably want to use a regex replace try this: \([^/]*\/

Comment: If you go to [http://regexpal.com/](http://regexpal.com/) you can paste the regex and your data to see how it works...

Comment: See my final answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bring up the Find dialog in Notepad++ (CTRL+F), then change the Search Mode at the bottom to Regular expression. Now copy this regex:

```
([^/]*\/
```

...and paste it into the Find what box, then click Find Next. If it finds your text pattern (which it should - I tested it), switch over to the Replace tab and go for it!